# Possible way of overloading functions or prototypes with different return data types RPGLE

Tags: function, prototype, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a procedure that returns a data type of char/packed/date based on the input parameters. I was thinking of possible ways to use overload, but IBM doesn't allowed overloading of prototypes that return different types of variables.

One way I have gotten around was by returning a data structure with all 3 data types starting at position 1 and just picking the one I need. So the code would look something like this.

Copy Source

```
dcl-ds myDs qualified;
   charData char(100) pos(1);
   packedData packed(10:3) pos(1);
   dateData date pos(1);
end-ds;
```

```
dcl-proc someProc export;
   dcl-pi someProc likeDS(myDS);
      x1;
      x2;
      x3;
   end-pi;

   doSomething;
end-proc;
```

Which requires to be used as:

```
dcl-s localChar char(100);
dcl-s localPacked packed(10:3);

myDs = someProc(par1:par2:par3);
localPacked = myDS.packedData;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to just skip the coding of myDS = someProc() and just code directly as localPacked = someProc();

if it makes a difference, the caller would know what type of data to get back as well as the result would be included in the calling parms.

I was reading up on pointers and was wondering if using pointers would solve my problem if I used *caller as actgrp. I am still new to RPG and still learning, so not too familiar with the pointers usage. Just learned procedures and prototypes, and their usage and how fun to use, so that's that's all basically I am coding now on free time.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if someone asks whether pointers would solve a problem, the answer is "no". Basically, you should only use pointers when two things are true: 1) You completely understand what is happening with the pointer for the full lifetime of the pointer. 2) Using pointers makes it easier for people to call your procedure, without them having to know anything about pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to RPG coding! :-)

I think your goal should be to make things as easy as possible for people who want to call your procedure. So I think you should create three procedures.

If the caller has to know the type of data returned, it's easier for them to just call the specific procedure. That way, the called procedure also knows what kind of data is wanted.

```
localPacked = someProcPacked(par1:par2:par3);
```

If all three procedures have a lot of code that is the same, you could put that code into a fourth procedure with the DS passed as a parameter. The real callers would not need to know about this procedure, so you would not export someProc().

```
dcl-proc someProcPacked export;
   dcl-pi *n Packed(10:3);
      x1;
      x2;
      x3;
   end-pi;
   dcl-ds ds likeds(myDs);

   someProc(ds : x1 : x2 : x3);
   // should you also tell someProc to give packed data?
   return ds.packedData;
end-proc;
```

Comment: As I read the question, seemed like the new `OVERLOAD` might be helpful?

Comment: OVERLOAD doesn't allow a different return type

Comment: Hi Barbara, thanks, loving the RPG concepts so far. Regarding having multiple procedures, I actually have 3 separate procedures names prefixed with returned data types. They are all overloaded on to a common name in a copy source.  The workaround of having all three returned types at position (1) of the returned data structure apparently allowed the overload.

Answer (score 1):

The first question that arose personally for me: as a consumer calling your function. must understand what type of result it will return to him?
Given that the possible types in your example are absolutely incompatible with each other.
One could understand if these were potentially compatible types, for example

```
char(26)
```

and

```
timestamp(6)
```

or

```
char(7)
```

and

```
zoned(7:0)
```

but

```
char(100)
packed(10:3)
date(1)
```

are not compatible with each other. If the function returns

```
packed(10:3)
```

and you try to interpret it as

```
char(100)
```

You will get complete nonsense. Otherwise, you risk getting an error.
In your case, one more field suggests itself in the resulting structure - the type of the result.
But in general, this is not a very good approach.
Overload is designed for when you have two or more functions that perform basically the same operation and return the same result. For example, the function of reading a message from the Data Queue is a possible option to unconditionally read the first available message, or (if it is a KEYED queue) read the message with the corresponding key value. In the first case, you only need to pass the name of the queue and the buffer for the message, in the second, you will also need to pass the key value.

```
dcl-pr ReadNoKey int(10);
  dtaqName       char(10)      const;
  dtaqLib        char(10)      const;
  msgBuff        char(65536)   options(*varsize);
  msgBuffLen     int(10)       value;
end-pr;

dcl-pr ReadKey int(10);
  dtaqName       char(10)      const;
  dtaqLib        char(10)      const;
  msgBuff        char(65536)   options(*varsize);
  msgBuffLen     int(10)       value;
  msgKey         char(256)     optopns(*varsize);
  msgKeyLen      int(10)       value;
end-pr;

dcl-pr Read int(10) overload(ReadNoKey: ReadKey);
```

In this case, you always call one Read function, and according to the set of parameters (passed the key or not), it is already clear what you want and what the program should do.
So it works